# Accessing an "instance" without an instance?

Tags: java

So, I'm thinking of creating a `JFrame` without making an instance of it.

This is how I normally do it:

```
package framecanvasagain;

public class Framecanvasagain {

    public MyFrame theframe;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creates the frame normally
        theframe = new MyFrame();

        //now let's say I want to access the frame again later on
        theframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
}
```

I could create a `JFrame` without creating an instance of it, but is there a way to access that `JFrame` later on?

```
package framecanvasagain;

public class Framecanvasagain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame(); //Netbeans says "New Instance Ignored" but it still loads a JFrame

        //now let's say I want to access the frame again later on
        MyFrame().setLocationRelativeTo(null); //this returns an error, "cannot find symbol"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *I could create a JFrame without creating an instance of it* - [you cannot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri yeah, you're right. `new MyFrame();` did create an instance of JFrame, but it doesn't have a "name." So, is there away to access that nameless JFrame again later on?

Comment: @Noob Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do. It is not clear what you are asking or what you are trying. What is the problem in saving the reference in a variable as normal? Where you want to access it?

Comment: Are you confusing "instance" with "variable"?

Comment: @khelwood yeah, I did confuse instance with variable. Thanks.

Comment: Despite what @NathanWalsh says at the bottom of his excellent answer, it sounds to me like maybe you DO want to create a singleton.  If so, check out the link in Nathan's answer.  Creating a singleton is an effective way of creating an object early on, not holding a reference to it, and then being able to access it again any time you want, anywhere in your code.  Sometimes, you don't explicitly create these objects in your code.  Rather, they are just created the first time they are referenced.  This is a very powerful and often used technique.

Comment: @Steve This is the first time I heard of "singleton." I'll go check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a Static Class for avoid instantiation, but here with JFrames is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. You need to set it to a variable in order to access it's properties again.

```
 new MyFrame();
```

creates an instance of the JFrame but the Java garbage collector picks it up right away since it isn't set to anything.

you could do this :

```
(new MyFrame()).setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

However, you would still be creating an instance of it and wouldn't be able to access its properties again.  There is no way to reuse an object without creating it and then storing it in Java.  The perils of an object orientated programming language.

Making it into a singleton might be an alternative.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/

Although, I don't think that's really what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I just thought "why do I have to create a variable for JFrame if I'm only using one JFrame?" Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean! Certain languages are more lenient on stuff like that but for Java if you don't have a reference to something it could be deleted at any time.  No questions are stupid! We have all been there.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title is incorrect:

What you are actually asking is:
*Can I access an instance without a reference to it?*

And the answer is: no, you can not!

In your example code you **do** create an instance of `JFrame` but you immediately discard the reference to it, so you have no way of addressing that particular instance.

Also, it may be garbage collected at any time (unless some internal part of the library is also holding a reference to it, I am not an expert in AWT internals), so your frame could disappear at random.

But the real question is: what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're asking by just adding a single word...`static`. Just make your `myFrame` variable `static`.  Here's your first example, modified a bit.  I moved the "do later" call into another method just to stress the point that your `MyFrame` can be accessed from anywhere:

```
package framecanvasagain;

public class Framecanvasagain {

    public static MyFrame theframe;

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        //now let's say I want to access the frame again later on
        Framecanvasagain.theframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creates the frame normally
        theframe = new MyFrame();

        ....

    }
}
```

Comment: you still create `theframe` variable. So, that's not really what I was imagining. I thought that since I only have one JFrame, maybe I can access it without creating a variable for it. I think I'm confusing everyone with my original question. But I'm already satisfied with the first answer. So, it's fine for this thread to just die. Updating it may just bump it again unnecessarily.

Comment: Ok.  Just dawned on me that if you were interested in a Singleton, you might want to see this too, which is a simpler version of the same thing really.

Comment: If static is a simpler version of singleton, then maybe I'd just go with that. Since I'm already familiar with static.